# Запустить Apache сервер на том же порту, что и Tomcat

Tags: spring, apache, tomcat, веб-сервер

Возможно ли запустить Tomcat сервер на том же порту (к примеру, 80 порт), что и Apache сервер? Если да, то как?

Просто интересуюсь. Чтобы не тратить время на компиляцию Spring-кода - я просто пишу HTML (иногда PHP) страницы и через FTP кидаю на сервер, чтобы открыть написанную страницу с мобильника и планшета. В тоже самое время я пишу админку (да и по сути весь сайт) на Java и как бы хотелось открывать ее на том же порту (80), что и мои HTML файлы, закинутые на сервак, вместо, чтобы писать `example.com:8080/admins`.

Дополнительно интересует вопрос:
Можно ли сделать так, чтобы основной домен работал на 80 порту, а субдомен - на другом (к примеру, 8080)?

*P.S. пожалуста, не пишите комментарии об абсурдности вопроса. Если такое невозможно, то напишите почему (желательно с указанием источника)*

Comment: Нельзя. Две разные программы не могут использовать один порт. Обычно это решается проксированием запросов к определённым URL на сервер запущенный на другом порте. Так же решается и вопрос с субдоменом.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev спасибо за ответ)

Comment: Можете, пожалуйста, записать Ваш ответ в раздел `Ответы` и повозможности его расширить

Comment: Можете, пожалуйста, записать Ваш ответ в раздел `Ответы` и повозможности его расширить

Comment: @Antonio112009, он не увидит ваши просьбы пока вы не добавите @

Comment: @Nick я те сообщения написал в одну секунду.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Данный ответ дан [Sergey Gornostaev](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/204271/sergey-gornostaev)

> Нельзя. Две разные программы не могут использовать один порт. Обычно
>   это решается проксированием запросов к определённым URL на сервер
>   запущенный на другом порте. Так же решается и вопрос с субдоменом.